# Reading plot names from folder using gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to make variable "list" containing filenames, variable "i" containing number of datafiles and plot it into single graph. Example of filenames: ConvAut.dat, ConvMoveAut.dat, CutAut.dat ...
Here is my try:

```
list = system("echo $(dir *.dat)")
plot for [1:i] i using 1:((2*i)+(column(2))) w steps tit i
```

I just found this piece of code but i dont know how to edit it.
I have version 4.6 patchlevel 0. Can you help me?
Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

```
list = system("dir /b *.dat") # Windows
# list = system("ls *.dat") # Unix
plot for [i=1:words(list)] word(list, i) using 1:((2*i)+column(2)) w steps title word(list, i)
```

The `list` is a string which contains all files, separated by white spaces. In the `plot` command you could also iterate over this file list with `plot for [file in list] file ...`, but then you don't have access to the file number. So I used `words` to get the number of files, and `word(list, i)` to get the i-th file name.

Note, that this works only if the file names don't contain white spaces.

Comment: In Unix, one way to handle file names containing white spaces is `list = system("ls *.txt | xargs -I line echo \\\"line\\\" ")`

Comment: @vagoberto Thanks for the addition. That would work with gnuplot 5, which has limited support for handling quoted strings with `word`.