# gnuplot with muliple columns using loop

Tags: shell, gnuplot, glob

I have a number of files (having 10 columns each) with following order:

```
file_001.txt, file_002.txt, file_003_txt,
file_021.txt, file_023.txt, file_023.txt,
file_041.txt, file_042.txt, file_043.txt,
file_061.txt, file_062.txt, file_063.txt,
file_081.txt, file_082.txt, file_083.txt,
```

I would like to plot each file with different line. e.g. using 1:2, using 1:3, using 1:5, using 1:8. I can not able to make a loop to call different columns. My following script is not working for k field

```
 plot for [k=2, 3, 5, 8] for [j=0:8:2] for [i=1:3] 'file_0'.j.i.'.txt' u 1:k;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `for [k in "2 3 5 8"]` if you have a list rather than a range.

Answer (score 2):

If `j` can be > 9, you should set up a function

```
fname(j,i) = sprintf("name%02.f%.f",j,i)
```

to get proper file names.

Format string "%02.f" means float (f), no digits after the comma (.), minimum two postions (2), fill empty space with zeroes.

```
print fname(2,3)
    name023

print fname(13,3)
    name133

print fname(113,3)
    name1133
```

These are libc format strings, they are not documented inside the gnuplot docs, but there are many sources in the web.